# Did you still want vs Do you still want

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-tense

Is it grammatically correct to ask:

**"Did you still want to go to the park today?"**

Or should it be:

**"Do you still want to go to the park today?"**

Comment: The past tense is often used to soften a present request. Both are correct, but the former is softer than the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Did you still want to go to the park today?

One of the uses for this form is to politely suggest reluctance on the part of the asker. By using the past tense there is a nuance that they hope the wanting is in the past.

Comment: That's funny -- I would say the opposite!  In my experience, this question is avoided when you're afraid the person has started to lose interest in going to the park today, but you want to go.

Answer (score 0):

> "Did you still want to go to the park today"

I think that should be only be used at the end of the day when people are talking about 'today' as something that has already gone past, technically when they don't have a chance to go to the park any more. That's just my personal opinion, though.

Answer (score -2):

Did is past tense. You haven't been to the park yet! The person is asking you. The verb tense should be future. "Would" you like to go......."

Comment: The word *still* does introduce a nuance which your suggestion loses by omitting it.